# When and best way to make exact copies of strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reference-type

Let's say I have an array of strings from executing this Split method

```
string[] parsed = message.Split(' ');
```

And then I want to store a certain value of this array in a new string

```
string name = parsed[3];
```

Now I remove this string from the array using an extension method, this method removes the value at the specified index and shifts everything back to fill the gap

```
parsed = parsed.RemoveAt(3);
```

I am aware that because strings are reference types in C# my name variable is now null, after searching a little I've been told that making exact copies of strings in C# is useless. What is the best and correct way to set the name variable as a new instance so that it does not get deleted after the .RemoveAt() call?

EDIT:

This is the best way that I found so far

```
string name = new string(parsed[3].ToCharArray());
```

Another way proposed by [Willy David Jr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6542896/willy-david-jr)

```
parsed = parsed.Where((source, index) => index != 3).ToArray();
```

EDIT 2:

Please disregard this question and read the approved answer, I misunderstood how reference types work.

Comment: Simply don't worry about it.  C# has automatic garbage collection. Let the collector do its job and you can worry about something else. Your belief that compacting the array changes the value of your local variable is false.

Comment: What makes you think `name` will be null after removing an element from the array?  `name` doesn't care about what happens to the array - it still contains a reference to the string you assigned it.

Comment: Well then I must be misunderstanding something about how references work, the string will still exist even after I remove it from the array? as far as I know it would be garbage collected because no other references will be pointing to it

Comment: @Michael Yes.  Removing an object from an array doesn't destroy the object - it just means that the *array* no longer contains a reference to the object.  Any other variables, etc. that were referencing the object will continue to do so.

Comment: It is good idea to try running code before asking question. So far post contains mostly imagined information without any code to back question up. Explaining all may be a bit too much for SO answer...

Comment: You write down "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC" on a piece of paper. You make a photocopy of that piece of paper. Did you just build a second White House? No. Then you erase the first piece of paper. Did you just destroy the White House? No. Did erasing one piece of paper erase the other? No. Then you burn both papers.  Did you just burn the White House down?  No. References are just *references* to a thing; they are not *the thing*, and two identical copies of a reference are aliases to *the thing*, not *each other*.

Comment: You may be of the belief that when you say `name = parsed[3]` that `name` becomes an alias *for the variable* `parsed[3]`.  That belief is false.  That means "make a copy of the value of `parsed[3]` and store that value in variable `name`".  In C# you *can* make an alias like that using `ref` and `out`, but this is relatively rare.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thank you folks who downvoted because I misunderstood how reference types work, and sincerely thank you for those who explained how it works to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how reference types work.  Removing an object from an array does not modify that object in any way - it just means that the array no longer contains a *reference* to the object.

You can test this yourself.  Run the code you included in the debugger (or a console app) and then view (or print out) the value of `name` at the end.

The thing that *can* trick you up with reference types occurs when there are two variables (or arrays or whatever) that hold a reference to the same object.  In this case, changes made to the object via one variable will be reflected when the object is accessed via another variable - it's the same object, but with two different variables *referencing* it.  If you want both variables to refer to their own "copy" of the object, you have to create a copy yourself and assign it to one of the variables.

However, in C#, the `string` type is *immutable*, meaning that once a `string` object is created there is no way to change that object.  So there is never a reason to create a copy of a string.  If there is a variable that references a particular string, you can be sure that no other reference can change it out from under you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think your `name` variable should be null? It will stay untouched after removal from array. Your original code is enough to accomplish what you desire.

Comment: How is it untouched if name is just pointing to the string in parsed[], which was removed

Comment: It is removed from array but `name` variable still points to that string. Read about C# basics before downvoting, please.

Comment: I did not downvote sir, in fact I don't have enough rep to vote on comments yet. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok, anyway, just create simple console app and put your code there. You will see that name variable contains the desired string without any copy attempts.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the answer. Also thanks to BJ Myers and dana for explaining how the String type works

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that there is RemoveAt at your string? There is RemoveAt on Collections but not on string or string array per se.

You can do this instead:

```
 List<string> lstParse = new List<string>();

 foreach (var i in parsed)
    {
       lstParse.Add(i);
    }
 string name = parsed[3];      
 lstParse.RemoveAt(3);
```

To join again the list and convert it to string:

```
string strResult = string.Join(" ", lstParse.ToArray());
```

If you really want to remove index without a new list of object, disregard the code above and you can do this one line instead:

```
 parsed = parsed.Where((source, index) => index != 3).ToArray();
```

Comment: They do mention that they added an extension method. What you are doing will give the same behaviour as the OP.

Comment: _using an extension method_ ?

Comment: If you want to join again the string after the removal, kindly check my updated code @Michael. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Seems like a good option but do I really have to create a whole new list object just to have a new instance of the previously deleted string

Comment: I updated my code if you don't want to create a new list of object. This will remove the index and will retain the instance. @Michael

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's probably the best way to do what I wanted. However I was misunderstanding the way reference types work, BJ Myers kindly explained it to me.

Comment: You're always welcome @Michael. You can remove the downvote if you did it, if not, well I cannot do anything about it.

Comment: I'm unable to downvote or upvote anything until I reach 15 reputation, wasn't me sorry :/

Comment: Okay no problem @Michael.